# Changing Model's primary key when defining a relation

Tags: php, orm, laravel-5.3

guys  in laravel relation, how can i change Model primary key on the fly?
like

```
/** table structures
* model1
* -- id (primary_key)
* -- uid (i just used this as an identifier to another model)
* model2
* -- id (primary_key)
*  -- uid (i just used this as an identifier to another model)
* model1_model2
* -- id
* -- model1_id (uid of model1)
* -- model2_id (uid of model2)
**/
// in Model1.php
public function relation()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Model2::class, 'model1_model2', 'mode1_id', 'mode2_id');
}
```

the question is.  how can i change the Model1 primary key when calling the `Model1::relation()` ??..

Comment: Eloquent only allows the model's primary key to be used in relationships. If you are using `uid` instead of `id` in relationships then consider telling laravel to use `uid` as the primary key, though you need to do this permanently by defining it in the model's `$primaryKey` property

Comment: @apokryfos but the uid is multiple and cannot have a duplicate values. afaik..

Comment: What do you mean? There's only 1 `uid` per table in your example here.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for pushing this old post. But recently I had the same problem and found just this post.

So I did some research and found out that since Version 5.5 Laravels `belongsToMany` method supports an `$parentKey` and `$relatedKey` variable as fifth and sixth parameter.
https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_belongsToMany